# Can you have function scope variables set automatically without defining the names in the function input

Tags: javascript, node.js, function

Take this snipper for example,

function test1 takes an object as input for arguments but defines the names of the properties which should be mapped into the function scope naturally via `({var0, var1, var0})`

(I'm not sure what to call these variables, scope variables??)

function test5 & test6 both take an object as input for arguments in the same way but 1 simply says `(args)` and the other tries to expand the incoming args into the arguments object via `({..args})`

what's interesting is the arguments object actually ends up looking the same in cases `test1 test5` & `test6` yet the scope variables are not the same.

Is there a way to achieve this functionality in an extensible way?

```js
// functionTest.js
function test1({var0, var1, var2}={}){
 console.log("*** test1 ***")
 console.log("this.var0", this.var0)
 console.log("arguments", arguments)
 console.log("var0", var0)
 console.log("var1", var1)
 console.log("var2", var2)
}
function test4(arguments){
 console.log("*** test4 ***")
 console.log("this.var0", this.var0)
 console.log("arguments", arguments)
 console.log("var0", var0)
}
function test5(args){
 console.log("*** test5 ***")
 console.log("this.var0", this.var0)
 console.log("arguments", arguments)
 console.log("var0", var0)
}
function test6({...args}){
 console.log("*** test6 ***")
 console.log("this.var0", this.var0)
 console.log("arguments", arguments)
 console.log("var0", var0)
}

let testValues = ["test0", "test1", "test2"]

try {
 test1({var0: testValues[0]})
} catch(error){console.error(error)}
try {
 test4({var0: testValues[0]})
} catch(error){console.error(error)}
try {
 test5({var0: testValues[0]})
} catch(error){console.error(error)}
try {
 test6({var0: testValues[0]})
} catch(error){console.error(error)}
```

Comment: what is the purpose of this? If you not even know what variables you intent to use, how can you write any code. This seems like the attempt at a solution to a problem that should not even exist.

Comment: @Thomas I write code which never errors

Answer (score -1):

It seems like it used to be possible with

```
with(args){
 // access to args.property via simply property
}
```

but that's been deprecated

the only way is now

```
Object.keys(args).forEach((key) => {
    Object.defineProperty(this, key, {
        value: args[key]
    });
});
```

which is.... alright I guess

Comment: did you check what `this` is, where you define your properties on? And did you check your code in [Strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode)?